# How to manipulate/hide slot elements in child components in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a named slot:

```
<div
      name="checkAnswer"
      class="w-[70%] mx-[15%] flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <button
        class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-md font-bold m-4 px-10 border-2 border-grey-800 hover:border-black hover:transition-all hover:duration-500"
      >
        <slot name="checkAnswer"></slot>
      </button>
    </div>
```

and then how i use it:

```
 <template #checkAnswer>
        <button
          @click="checkAnswer"
          :disabled="isAnswerChecked"
          :class="{
            ' text-gray-300 border-gray-300  ': isAnswerChecked,
          }"
        >
          Check answer
        </button>
      </template>
```

i have to use button tag in component in order to use @click, since I cant put @clikck on template element.

And there s a problem. When the button check answer is clicked, the correct answers are shown and I want to hide this button. But i cant hide it. I cant use v-show on template element, if i use it in button, the text of button is hidden, but i get empty button with no text.

I tried puting div inside template, outside template but i cant figure out a way the hide whole button not only a text of a button.

Comment: First of all, nested `<button>`s are illegal HTML.  Secondly, a slot is primarily a mechanism for replacing some default markup with another one, provided by the parent. You don't seem to need one here, because a) you don't have a default markup and b) you don't seem to need to reuse this component in multiple parents so each would provide a different slot content.

Comment: Here's an example most likely [achieving what you want](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-danny-ml8pzt?file=/src/Question.vue) without the need to use slots.

Comment: thanks sir for your time; i have a QuestionCard component that consists of Question Title, Answers and buttons, and thats why i use named slots. I prefer slots more than props because i could use use in multiple places as the app grows. Im also learning Vue Options API so i cant now fully understand your code in Compositions API. and your advanced JS. Thanks for your time but i dont know how to get rid of nested button as i cant use @click on template, and i dont know how to fix this without rebuliding the app from scractch.

Comment: What you shared so far is not enough to go on so we could understand your problem. This is likely an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

What are you trying to do is to pass a component attributes to a specific NON-root element.

For that you should turn off automatic inheritance of attributes to a root of a component with `inheritAttrs: false` and assign the attributes manually to your element of choice with the `$attrs` variable in the template;

About disabling attribute inheritance in the Vue docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

The slot is not needed here (besides passing a custom button label) and you try to insert a button into a button hoping that would merge into 1 button with the expected behavior which is definitely won't work.

So the your component Answer.vue:

```
<script>
    export default {
        inheritAttrs: false
    };
</script>

<template>
<div
      name="checkAnswer"
      class="w-[70%] mx-[15%] flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <button
        v-bind="$attrs"
        class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-md font-bold m-4 px-10 border-2 border-grey-800 hover:border-black hover:transition-all hover:duration-500"
      >
      <slot name="checkAnswer">Check answer</slot>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>

  import {ref} from 'vue';
    import Answer from './Answer.vue';

  const isAnswerChecked = ref(false);

</script>

<template>
  <answer 
    @click="isAnswerChecked = true" 
    :disabled="isAnswerChecked"
          :class="{
            ' text-gray-300 border-gray-300  ': isAnswerChecked,
          }">
    <template #checkAnswer>
      Check answer carefully
    </template>
  </answer>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks sir for your time; i have a QuestionCard component that consists of Question Title, Answers and buttons, and thats why i use named slots. Thanks for your time but i dont know how to get rid of nested button as i cant use @click on template, and i dont know how to fix this without rebuliding the app from scractch.

Comment: @user21903805 i provided a real working solution just incorporate it into your components. moreover i doubt anybody else will answer here with a such detailed answer so you could accept my answer ( the checkbox ) so i will be rewarded with points and motivated to help you in the future, thanks